# Can one prove the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ by the absolute convergence criterion of infinite products?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Euler proved this celebrated theorem that $\sum \frac{1}{p}=\infty$ by using the product formula that $\displaystyle \zeta (s)=\prod \left( \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\right)$.

Now I thought of another proof(whose validity I am uncertain about, and that's why this question was raised), which begins with recognising the divergence of the harmonic series $\sum n^{-1}$, and then if $\sum p^{-1}$ converges, the convergence is absolute and thus the product $\prod (1-p^{-1})=1/\zeta(1)=0$ should converge absolutely. But it is zero, yet no factor of it is zero, so it must have diverged to $0$, contradiction.

Comment: What's the difference? One product is the reciprocal of the other, for $s=1$.

Comment: @user180040: Technically speaking, both sides of the equation are not defined for $ s = 1 $.

Comment: That's the point, they're $+\infty$.

Comment: That's why I took the reciprocal, and define $1/\zeta(1)=0$ (removable singularity!)

Comment: I guess it comes down to the details of how you prove the equality you wrote. I don't see any way other than doing it by considering the original product formula.

Comment: Maybe in the original product formula we let $s\to 1$?

Comment: Maybe. But anything you say about $1/\zeta(1)$ is ultimately likely to derive from something you say about $\zeta(1)$. I would do the proof this way. The product $\prod 1/(1-p^{-1})$ is increasing. To prove that it diverges, it's enough to prove that it's unbounded above. This will be achieved if you can prove that given any fixed $n$, there is some partial product that exceeds the $n$th partial sum of the harmonic series. This can in turn be done by bounding the factor $1/(1-p^{-1})$ below by $1 + p^{-1} + \dots + p^{-e}$, where $p^e$ is the largest power of $p$ that is $\leq n$.

Comment: And then stopping at the factor $1/(1-p^{-1})$ where $p$ is the largest prime that is $\leq n$.

Comment: If we truncate the product, define $p (n, s)=\prod _{p_1=2} ^{p_n} (1-1/{{p_n}^{-s}})$ the conclusion cam be derived from that $ p (n,1)\to 0$ as $ n\to \infty $(the convergence of the partial product to zero is called diverge to zero and is taken care of by the absolute convergence criterion! ) . And this can be achieved by proving the uniformity of the convergence as $ n\to \infty $ in $ s $(on a compact interval). Principle of analytic continuation gives that $ p (\infty,1)=0$. That's my idea.

Comment: And I believe the uniformity of the convergence of $ p (n, s) $ in $ s $ is really proved by dominating the product for $ 1\leq s \leq 2$ by $ s=2$.

Comment: It's hard for me to follow this proof. I would probably need to see it written out to understand it.